# MySQL: Select between dates dd.mm.yyyy hh.mm.ss

Tags: mysql, date, select, between

what mysql syntax I can use to select data from a mysql table based on "between dates"?
I have a column that contains only dates in format like: 08.05.2016 18:09:31 (dd.mm.yyyy hh.mm.ss)

Comment: That is not the standard format of a DateTime column. Are you sure the actual data in the column is in that format? Is this column a DateTime column or a VARCHAR

Comment: You should fix the data structure and store date/times using the native `date`/`datetime` types.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you made an early error in your database design and put a date and time into a varchar or some kind of string column type.

So in that case you need to convert the string into a proper MYSQL DateTime and then you can use the `BETWEEN` syntax

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(sillyDateColumn, '%d.%m.%Y %h:%i:s') 
           BETWEEN '2016-01-01 00:00:01' AND '2016-01-02 00:00:01'
```

> For future reference always store Dates or Time or DateTime values in appropriate MYSQL data types i.e. DATE or TIME or DATETIME
>
> If your users want to see these values presented differently on there systems, format the dates to locale specific formats for and in the presentation layer only.

If I am wrong and these dates are in a DATETIME type column then all you need to do is

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
WHERE DateColumn BETWEEN '2016-01-01 00:00:01' AND '2016-01-02 00:00:01'
```

Comment: My application put the date in a column type like varchar. My date format is something like 08.05.2016 18:09:31. If I use this code: SELECT * FROM `tichete` 
where 
    data_creare >='01.04.2016 21:31:48' and data_creare <='05.05.2016 21:58:29'; is working ok. I get the data between that values, but if i replace  and data_creare <='05.05.2016 21:58:29'; with  and data_creare <='31.05.2016 2222:22'; for ex, I get all the results from the table. 05.05.2016 21:58:29 is a value that exist in a row

Comment: Did you actually try the first example I suggested.